# Mimic Magnetic Repulsive Resistance through a spring

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, spring

I have two identical magnets and I push them towards each other so that they are repelling.

Is it possible to accurately mimic this repulsion effect (magnetic energy) just using a metal spring (mechanical energy)?

Or is the rate at which the *strength of magnetic repulsion in ratio to distance of end points of the magnets* changes different than the rate at which the *strength of repulsion (spring) in ratio to the distance of the end points of a spring* changes?

^Sorry if that sentence made no sense, it's hard to word in an easy to understand manner. I'll try saying it again, but using substitution, below:

Or is the rate at which X changes different than the rate at which Y changes?

X = *the strength of magnetic repulsion in ratio to distance of end points of the magnets*

Y = *the strength of repulsion (spring) in ratio to the distance of the end points of a spring*

---

(p.s. obviously it's not possible to exactly duplicate the repulsion effect, just like it would be impossible to duplicate the repulsion of two magnets, using those same exact two magnets at a later time... I'm just talking about getting 99.999999% duplication for all intents and purposes.) So that "X" and "Y" would have the same mathematical function, down to like a gazillion decimal places (but not "exact" technically speaking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is impossible, with a spring you get a repulsion force proportional to $c-x$, where $c$ is a constant, the magnetic force instead depends on the shapes of the magnets (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets), but increase much faster as $x$ becomes smaller (for instance it is proportional to $1/x^2$ for cylindrical magnets at medium range and grows still faster at closer range (proportional to $1/x^4$)

Comment: What a shame /: Thanks for your answer! I don't suppose there is a way to shape these magnets for it to become possible? I supposed I could always build a mechanical device other than a spring that mimics it haha!